# Second round of revisions using the changes package

Tags: changes, trackchanges

We have used the changes package with the "review" option to revise our paper and resubmit it. The reviewers agreed with all changes, but asked for more. So, we now need to incorporate all previous changes (select option "final" for those), and start a new round of changes using the commands \chadded{}, \chdeleted{} etc anew. However, it seems that we are stuck with either showing all changes, current and previous ones (if we select "review"), or none (if we select "final") in the options of the package "changes".

Is there a way to incorporate the previous round of changes and start a new one?

Comment: You have to remove the commands by hand or use the script (see Section 5 of `changes` manual).

Comment: the solution of the script is not really effective. It has a known issue: – removes only markup that is used in one line, not markup that spans multiple lines